# Image media is not getting upload on AWS S3 media folder-CKEditor

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ckeditor

When I was uploaded image from backend django admin then the image is not getting upload on aws s3 media folder with name django-ckeditor-5/example.img. It is creating one folder with name django-ckeditor-5 on local server. but Not uploading on aws s3 media folder.
I have tried these both  path but not working
`url(r'^ckeditor5/(?P<path>.*)/?$', include('django_ckeditor_5.urls')),` and
`path("ckeditor5/", include('django_ckeditor_5.urls')),`

Click [here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/63517784/85088487-8a577700-b1e0-11ea-8114-56d521ea9fb3.png) to see the image of problems.

below is my settings.py configuration for aws and media url

```
STATIC_URL = 's3url/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATIC_ROOT = "s3url/static/"
MEDIA_URL = 's3url/media/'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = ''
PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'SOME-bucket'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = ''
AWS_LOCATION = ''
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL= None
```